# Given $a, b$ in the group $G$, then the equations $a\cdot x = b$ and $y\cdot a = b$ have unique solutions for $x$ and $y$ in $G$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Given $a, b$ in the group $G$, then the equations $a \cdot x = b$ and $y \cdot a = b$ have unique solutions for $x$ and $y$ in $G.$

This is a very common property of groups. Maybe, there are similar threads in the forum, but I want to verify a proof. My solution goes like this:

> Given $a\cdot x=b$, we see that, if $x=a^{-1}\cdot b$, then $a\cdot x= (a\cdot a^{-1})\cdot b=e\cdot b=b.$ Also, in the case of $y\cdot a=b$, we see that $y=b\cdot a^{-1}$, so then, $y\cdot a=b\cdot (a^{-1}\cdot a)=b$.

Is the proof alright? And $x$ has no other solutions apart from $a^{-1}\cdot b$, as it is a linear equation, right? Is this sufficient to prove the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: To prove uniqueness, you need to argue that if the equation $a \cdot x = b$ has a solution $x$, then multiplying on the left by $a^{-1}$ you get that $x$ is uniquely determined as $a^{-1} \cdot b$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti do u mean to say that $x$ must have no other solutions other than $a^{-1}.b$ ...is the argument that should be given to prove the uniqueness...with the method u described?...

Comment: In this, and in more intricate situations, it is useful to prove uniqueness first. That is, you assume as I did that there is a solution, and show that this is uniquely determined. Then, as you did, verify that this is indeed a solution. The reason for this second step is that if there is no solution, and you assume there is one (as I did in the uniqueness part), if you get something, this will be meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave **A** solution to $ax=b$, but you did not show that it is **the only** solution.

Let's show that the equation $ax=b$ has at most one solution. We do this by showing the following: If $x$ and $x'$ are distinct elements in $G$ then $ax$ and $ax'$ are also distinct. Suppose otherwise: that $x$ and $x'$ are distinct elements in $G$ satisfying $ax=ax'$. Then let $a^{-1}$ be $a$'s inverse in $G$.

1. Then on the one hand
   $a^{-1}ax = (a^{-1}a)x = x$.
2. But then also $a^{-1}ax = a^{-1}(ax)$ $= a^{-1}(ax')$ [because $ax=ax'$] $=(a^{-1}a)x' =x'$.

Do you see the contradiction between 1. and 2.?

And then can you use the above to show that the equation $ya=b$ has at most $1$ solution?

Answer (score -1):

You have not demonstrated uniqueness in either case.

To this end, suppose $as=b$ and $at=b$. Then $as=at$, which implies

$$\begin{align}
s&=es\\
&=(a^{-1}a)s\\
&=a^{-1}(as)\\
&=a^{-1}(at)\\
&=(a^{-1}a)t\\
&=et\\
&=t.
\end{align}$$

This establishes uniqueness. Then if $ax=b$, we have $x=a^{-1}b$, which will be the only solution by uniqueness.

The case $ya=b$ is entirely analogous.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing....this answer is good and correct. It was more to the point than my answer here infact [cross-posted], and should be the answer accepted. +1